# PerformancePoint Export Capabilities

Tags: performancepoint

Does PerformancePoint has features like export to excel or to pdf? I want to have a report that can be filtered by month using a dropdown. Then I should be able to export it to excel or pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should. PerformancePoint gives your this functionality through the webpart options.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSip5nWM5is